# Bundle rows in SQL Server from one "start" to "end"

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with rows I need to separate.

The discernable information is that the beginning of one row is "Start" and the beginning of another one is "end"

```
|     time            |     action       |     user         |
+---------------------+------------------+------------------+
|       12:00         |       Start      |       1          |
|       12:01         |       xxxx       |       1          |
|       12:02         |       End        |       1          |
|       12:03         |       Start      |       1          |
|       12:04         |       xxxx       |       1          |
|       12:05         |       End        |       1          |
|       12:06         |       Start      |       2          |
|       12:07         |       xxxx       |       2          |
|       12:08         |       End        |       2          |
```

I would like to add a column that would identify each block from start to end including the xxx in the middle

Comment: I think you're going to need to have another go t this question. I really don't understand what you want to do or where or why. Of course might just me not understanding...

Comment: its a log table where events are recorded.
I want to bundle the events from start to end. 
for example in the example above 2 runs happened with 1 step in between, the steps are variable though

Answer (score 1):

I started off trying to use the [LAG()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function to look back at the previous record and increment the bundle number if the previous action is "End". I couldn't get that to work so here is my solution using a common table expression. It seems overly complicated, but it works. Perhaps it could be simplfied.

```
DECLARE @Actions TABLE
(
    [time] CHAR(5)
  , [action] VARCHAR(10)
);

INSERT INTO @Actions
(
    time
  , action
)
VALUES
('12:00', 'Start')
, ('12:01', 'xxxx')
, ('12:02', 'End')
, ('12:03', 'Start')
, ('12:04', 'xxxx')
, ('12:05', 'End');

;WITH cte1 AS
(
    SELECT
          x.row
        , x.time
        , x.action
        , 1 AS [bundle]
    FROM  (
              SELECT
                   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY time) AS [row]
                 , time
                 , action
              FROM @Actions
          ) x
    WHERE x.row = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
               y.row
             , y.time
             , y.action
             , CASE
                   WHEN cte1.action = 'End' THEN
                       cte1.bundle + 1
                   ELSE
                       cte1.bundle
               END AS [bundle]
    FROM       (
                   SELECT
                        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY time) AS [row]
                      , time
                      , action
                   FROM @Actions
               ) y
    INNER JOIN cte1 ON y.row - 1 = cte1.row
    WHERE      y.row > 1
)
SELECT cte1.row, cte1.time, cte1.action, cte1.bundle FROM cte1;
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=04782b97536e392dcc535afa5567bb97).

Comment: I think I have tooo many rows

Msg 530, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The statement terminated. The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion.

Comment: Updated the [sql fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=855b1a8127c8ccc2f7d7cc073e98ce0d)

Answer (score 1):

The suggestion from Isaac gave me an idea. It's ugly but it works.
created a new column in the select with a case, when it finds a start = 1
created another column that does the running sum by looking at lower rows that match the user.